# Most space efficient encoding that generate printable string in PHP?

Tags: php, hash, base64, md5

I have a large string `$string` that when applied to `md5()`, give me

```
c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
```

The length is 32, I want to reduce it, so

```
base64_encode(md5($string, true));

xMpCOKC5I4INzFCab3WEmw==
```

Removing the last two `==` it give me a string with length = 22.

Are there any other better algorithms?

Comment: An option is to compress the string.  What is it that you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: In general, the larger the alphabet you are allowed to use the fewer characters it will take to encode your value. Only you can say what alphabet size you can use.

Comment: What is your plan with the final string? Is it for comparisment of large strings? So you just want to get an almost unique hash of it?

Comment: How short is short enough?

Comment: @devnull: Compression probably wouldn't help with a random-looking hex string (like a hash).  The info needed to decompress it would probably exceed the bytes saved.

Comment: @cHao You're right.  Didn't realize that.

Comment: You could convert it back to it's pre md5 string "1". http://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b. That's reduced ;P. Either that or you could give us a better clue as to what you are trying to do so we can give you a solution that addresses the root issue.

Comment: @Gerry, `md5 is an irreversible algorithm` - this website doesn't "convert it back" - it basically has stored someone's input "1" with the resulting md5 sum and matched it. However "1" is only one of possible results. `For any md5 sum there is an infinite number of strings that get reduced to this single md5 sum.`

Comment: @Ryan, it's very important to know if you are going to get the original string back from your "shortened" one. If so, then md5 is a no-go.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I know, I was making a point that we need more info about what he is actually trying to solve.

Comment: We really do need more detail on what exactly you're trying to achieve in order to provide the best response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shortest possible hash value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046906/shortest-possible-hash-value)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure you realised that `md5` is a hash function, and therefore irreversible. If you do not care about reversibility, you could just as well trim the `md5` hash (or any hash of your liking*) down to an arbitrary number of characters. All this would do is increase the likelihood of collision (I *feel* this does not produce an uniform distribution though).

If you are looking for a reversible (ie. non-destructive) compression, then do not reinvent the wheel. Use the built-in functions, such as [`gzdeflate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.gzdeflate.php) or [`gzcompress()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php), or [other similar functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php).

---

**Here is a [list of hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) (wikipedia) along with the size of their output.
I suppose the smallest possible "hash function" would be a [parity bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) :)*

Answer (score 2):

One better way would be to, instead of converting to binary to hexadecimal (as md5 does) and then converting the *string* to base64, instead convert from the hexadecimal md5 directly to base64.

Since hexadecimal is 16 bits per character, and base64 is 64 bits per character, every 2 hexadecimal characters will make up one base64 character.

To perform the conversion, you can do the following:

- Split the string into sixteen 2 character chunks
- The first character should be multiplied by 2 and added to the second (keeping in mind that A-F = 10-15).
- This number can be matched to the base64 scheme using the table from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

This will result in a 16 character base64 string with the same value as the hexadecimal representation of the md5 string.

Theoretically, you could do the same for any base. If we had a way to encode base128 strings in ASCII, we could end up with an 8 character string.  However, as the character set is limited, I think base64 is the highest base that is commonly used.

Comment: Easier way: pass `true` as the second argument to `md5()` to get it to return raw output.

Answer (score 2):

The smaller the `length` of the string you want .. the smaller the number of `possible combination`

Total Number of Possibility with reputation

> Total Possibility  = n<sup>r</sup>

Since we are dealing with [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) has the printable output this means we only have 64 characters

```
 n = 64
```

If you are looking at 22 letters in length

> n<sup>r</sup> = 64<sup>22</sup> = 5,444,517,870,735,015,415,413,993,718,908,291,383,296 possibilities

**Back to your question : Are there any better algorithm?**

Truncate the string with a good hash to desired length you want since the total possibility and collision is fixed

```
$string = "the fox jumps over the lazy brown dog";
echo truncateHash($string, 8);
```

Output

```
9TWbFjOl
```

Function Used

```
function truncateHash($str, $length) {
    $hash = hash("sha256", $str, true);
    return substr(base64_encode($hash), 0, $length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This encoding generates shorter string,

```
print base64_encode(hash("crc32b",$string,1));
```

output

```
qfQIdw==
```

Comment: CRC32 is an irreversible transformation. You might as well just truncate the hash.

Comment: @duskwuff `md5` is also irreversible transformation, they are both `hashing algorithms`

Comment: so, we have every ±2^32 strings a collision? _I like brute-force…_

Comment: @bwoebi it depends on OP where he want to use such hash, but it seems that hash length is critical in this particular case. As for security concerns there are `sha256` and `sha512` which are replacements for weak `md5`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if MD5 is the right choice for you, but i will assume that you have reason to stick with this algorithm and are looking for a shorter representation. There are several possibilities to generate a shorter string with different alphabets:

### **Option 1: Binary string**

The shortest possbile form of an MD5 is it's binary representation, to get such a string you can simply call:

```
$binaryMd5 = md5($input, true);
```

This string you can store like any other string in a database, it needs only 16 characters. Just make sure you do a proper escaping, either with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or with parametrized queries (PDO).

### Option 2: Base64 encoding

Base64 encoding will produce a string with this alphabet: [0-9 A-Z a-z + /] and uses '=' as padding. This encoding is very fast, but includes the sometimes unwanted characters '+/='.

```
$base64Md5 = base64_encode(md5($input, true));
```

The output length will be always 24 characters for the MD5 hash.

### **Option 3: Base62 encoding**

The base62 encoding only uses the alphabet [0-9 A-Z a-z]. Such strings can be safely used for any purpose like tokens in an URL, and they are very compact. I wrote a [base62 encoder](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/StoPasswordReset.html#StoBase62Encoder), which is able to convert binary strings to the base62 alphabet. It may not be the fastest possible implementation, but it was my goal to write understandable code. The same class could be easily adapted to different alphabets.

```
$base62Md5 = StoBase62Encoder::base62encode(md5($input, true));
```

The output length will vary from 16 to 22 characters for the MD5 hash.

Answer (score 0):

[Base 91](http://base91.sourceforge.net/) looks like the most space efficient binary to ASCII printable encoding algorithm (which is what it seems you want).

I've not seen the PHP implementation, but if your software has to work with others I'd stick to Base 64; it's well-known, lightning fast, and available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to answer your question: Yes, there is a better algorithm (if with "better" you mean  "shorter").

Use the [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function (which has been part of the PHP core and enabled by default since PHP 5.1.2.) with any of the `adler32`, `fnv132`, `crc32`, `crc32b`, `fnv132` or `joaat` algorithms.

Without a more in-depth knowledge of your current situation, you might as well just pick whichever one you think sounds the coolest.

Here is an example:

```
hash('crc32b', $string)
```

I set up [an online example](http://ideone.com/zwHzkd) you can play around with.

Secondly, I would like to point out that what you are asking is an almost exact duplicate of [another question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046906/shortest-possible-hash-value).

Answer (score 0):

I read from your post that you are searching for a hashing algorithm and not compression.

There are various standard hashing algorithms in php out there. Have a look at PHP [hashing functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.hash.php). 
Depending on what you want to hash there are different approches. Be careful and calculate the average collision probability.

However it seems you are searching for a 'compression' which outputs the minimum possible size of chars for a given string. If you do, then have a look at [Lempel–Ziv–Welch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) ([php implementation](https://code.google.com/p/php-lzw/)) or [others](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Compression/Dictionary_compression#LZW).